# multi level menu in iPhone

Tags: iphone, menu

I want to show a menu like the below image in iPhone

[image: menu]

is it possible to navigate like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement following code for multilevel Uitable view

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";   
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    [cell setIndentationLevel:[[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"level"] intValue]]; 
    return cell;
}
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath Method

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        NSDictionary *d=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
            NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"Objects"];
            BOOL isAlreadyInserted=NO;
            for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ){
                NSInteger index=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
                isAlreadyInserted=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
                if(isAlreadyInserted) break; 
            }
            if(isAlreadyInserted) {
                [self miniMizeThisRows:ar];
            } else {        
                NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
                NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
                for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
                    [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                    [self.arForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
                }
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            }
        }
    }
```

miniMizeThisRows method for the expanding the items

```
-(void)miniMizeThisRows:(NSArray*)ar{
    for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
        NSUInteger indexToRemove=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];     
        NSArray *arInner=[dInner valueForKey:@"Objects"];
        if(arInner && [arInner count]>0){
            [self miniMizeThisRows:arInner];
        }
        if([self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner]!=NSNotFound) {
            [self.arForTable removeObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:
              [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:0]]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
        }
    }
}
```

[For more detail visit the Reference Link for the Tutorial and grab the source code form here](http://sugartin.info/2011/07/20/447/)

Comment: Thanks neon samuel. This is working.

Comment: hey, I want this tableview with horizontal scrolling also. How can I do this?

Comment: For that you need to visit following post for that http://goo.gl/RxQBU

Comment: Ok.. I checked the link which you provided. But in that it is tableview with horizontal scrolling row is there. I want to scroll the whole tableview itself horizontally..

Comment: what i do to navigate to fully opened categoty to another controller????